# SSDT crashes when loading SSIS packages or new project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016

With the release of SSDT 2016 (GA), I've loaded SQL Server 2016 GA Developer Edition, the new SSMS 2016 stand-alone build, and even Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 (Professional edition) and Visual Studio still crashes anytime I attempt to open an SSIS package or create a new solution using the SSIS template (including the import wizard). I've reinstalled using the suggested order (SQL Server 2016, SSMS, SSDT) as well as just Visual Studio 2015 followed by SSDT. Both result in the same crash. I'm able to create and open all other solution types (SSRS, SSAS, SQLCLR) so it seems to be an issue specific to SSIS. The Connect bug report can be found (along with the attachments and everything MSFT has asked for) here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2781125/ssis-projects-crash-visual-studio

The error in Visual Studio is as follows:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  14.0.25420.1
  Application Timestamp:    57685d85
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18340
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5736541b
  Exception Code:   c06d007e
  Exception Offset: 00014878
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: d3a5
  Additional Information 2: d3a5b2a34c74c92cf7c3ff2061a46015
  Additional Information 3: 86f5
  Additional Information 4: 86f5db7ad561caf63ca32f7aba7c4416
```

Comment: Not seeing this on my side, but I also had every version/tool installed along the way. Have you tried repairing/reinstalling?

Comment: Those are independent of your issues - it's SSIS that's having trouble. What you are seeing is the DacFx (for SQL Server Object Explorer / SQL Projects) looking for optional internal extension DLLs. It logs not finding these as an error which causes the confusion.

Comment: yes, I've repaired/reinstalled each of the tools with no change in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception code c06d007e is "Delay-load module not found", so you are missing a DLL.

To debug it you can track DLL loading attempts using Process Monitor:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

or older FileMon:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx

After you find which dll is missing you can try to extract it manually from distribution or install all the components on clear system and copy needed DLL from there.

Comment: the issue turned out to be with [Traps](https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/products/secure-the-endpoint/traps.html) blocking certain DLL loads the first time VS loaded. Process Monitor provided a ton of processes that I couldn't sort through but it lead me to check whether I would have the same issue once our LAN team disabled Traps explicitly.