# Cannot have Excel and SSDT in the same machine

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2015, ssis, ms-office, sql-server-data-tools

Currently, I'm expressing an error when I'm trying to work in Excel as OLE Db data source. The error from the event viewer is as follows:

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85
>   Faulting module name: mso40uiwin32client.dll, version: 16.0.4510.1001, time stamp: 0x58aea30f
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x001665c1
>   Faulting process id: 0x1634
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d2a4d1d4ef28d1
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso40uiwin32client.dll
>   Report Id: c15c623e-10c5-11e7-81d4-782bcbacd899

What I'm trying to do: loading data from the excel file and put in sql database. When I create my package at the first time everything work ok, but when I closed and reopen my project I have VS crashing due to the error I reported from the event viewer.

From the error of the event viewer, I had the idea to uninstall office, install only ACE and try again to reopen and work in my project. The project worked again.

My understanding now, is that we cannot have office installed when we want to work with excel as OLE DB Source. Is this true?
Can any one help me to overcome this error? I want to have Excel and be able to work in my SSIS project in the same machine

Thank you

Comment: try this : its a known bug for VS-2015 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624438/ssdt-crashes-when-loading-ssis-packages-or-new-project

Comment: Thank you for this, but after more investigation the error tell that we have a conflict for the file mso40uiwin32client.dll

Comment: Why can't you use Excel Data Source? Is there any specific need to use OLE DB Data Source for Excel file? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/excel-source

Comment: Possibly dealing with Excel ".xlsx" versions?

Comment: This come from specification, we have to use only OLE DB. For the Excel, file we have source as 'xlsm' and 'xlsx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of install/uninstall SSDT2012.
We found that we are able to overcome the conflict issue when installing the SSDT2012 from this location:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015

I cannot explain why this version can resolve the issue, but what I understand that with this newer version of SSDT2012 we have several enhancement like creating database project in 2012, using sql server 2014 without any trouble, ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure:

- The version of the driver (Microsoft Jet /ACE) support the version of the excel you are trying to load.
- You can load and preview the Excel in the dataflow in a excel component, and see the info you are looking for.
- Sometimes the problem is that your driver is for 32bits and ssis runs on 64bits, you can change this from project to 32bits. I think this is the most important check and your fail could be this.
- Check the security of the file, ensure that you can access it and the user you are running ssis have permission.

put here the result of the execution of the package, to read more about the error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have done all of these steps before, and is not working. This is why I go to the event viewer to have more detail in what is going wrong